# How to get pagestate rolodexState in unittest with corresponding ids's

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, list-view, urlhacking

I have a button on the contact list pagelayout. The functionality of the button is to select multiple records and pass the ids to a visualforce page to start a flow through url.

When creating a unittest I had to rebuild the url which had several parameters. I hardcoded these to check if this works. but to be able to deploy I suppose I need to create these as testdata or are these the same in sandbox as in production?.

How to get or create

```
- pagestate and id?
- rolodexState and id?
- fcf?
```

Pageref

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.MultiselectContacts;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('00B240000000000_pageState','1');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('00B240000000000_rolodexState','-1');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('fcf','00B240000000000');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('ids','0031p0000000000');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('retURL','/003?');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('returnIds',recordId.substring(0,recordId.length()-3));
        system.debug('pageRef: '+pageRef);
```

Example url

```
/apex/MultiselectContacts?00B240000000000_pageState=1&00B240000000000_rolodexState=-1&fcf=00B240000000000&ids=0031p0000000000&retURL=%2F003%3Ffcf%3D00B240000000000&scontrolCaching=1&mailing=mailing&wrapMassAction=1
```

Comment: are you using a standardsetcontroller in your VF controller?

Comment: @cropredy yes I am because I am using"recordSetVar="record" to get the selected records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unit testing standardsetcontrollers, one doesn't normally construct the URL parameters because the VF controller has access to what is provided in URL params using methods. [Apex doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm?search_text=standardsetcontroller)

- `getSelected()` and `setSelected(SObject[] sobjects)`
- `getFilterId()`
- `getListViewOptions()` // returns available filters for use in setFilterId()

The unit test method should mock some Sobjects to simulate the user action of multi-selecting (checkboxes) records in a list view. You would not want to hard code any filterIds as the filters (especially custom filters) could disappear in your org due to some admin or empowered user action.

Here is a simple example

> The VF Controller

```
public class SSCExample {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc;

    public SelectOption[] listViews {get { return ssc.getListViewOptions();} private set;}
    public Sobject[] selectedRecs {get {return ssc.getSelected();} private set;}

    public SSCExample (ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc) {this.ssc = ssc;}
}
```

> The VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Order" extensions="SSCExample" recordSetVar="orders">
</apex:page>
```

> The VF controller test method

```
@istest static void testController() {
    // mock some Orders ... (not shown)

    // Given a StandardSetController
    ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
                                              [Select id from Order limit 20]);

    // Given user selection of some of the Orders
    ssc.setSelected([Select id from Order limit 5]);

    // Given a controller extension
    SScExample mySSC = new SSCExample(ssc);

    // mySSC.listViews will return SelectOptions where each SelectOption is 
    // a filterId + name for each available listView on Order given the running user's permissions. You can choose one and use it in a ssc.setFilterId(..) if the VF controller cares about filterIds
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,mySSC.listViews);
    // assertions as needed

    // mySSC.selectedRecs returns the 5 Sobjects you defined in the ssc.setSelected above. This might be useful in assertions
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,mySSC.selectedRecs);
    // assertions as needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking for this. I fugured out that de filter ids are the same across sanbox and production.

Comment: This probably won't be true if you create your listview (which is the object with the "00B" object prefix) in your sandbox and then deploy them to production. The Ids would normalize after you refresh your sandbox (after deploying to prod). Just something to be aware of.